# How to recover open but deleted file on Linux using ln instead of cp?

Tags: linux, file-recovery

I have a file that's downloading (from a source that's hard to re-download from), but accidentally deleted from the filesystem namespace (/tmp/blah), and I'd like to recover this file.

Normally I could just `cp /proc/$PID/fd/$FD /tmp/blah`, but in this case that would only get me a partial snapshot, since the file is still downloading. Furthermore, once the download completes, the downloading process (e.g. Chrome) will close the FD.

Any way to recover by inode/create a hard link? Any other solutions? If it makes any difference, I'm mainly concerned with ext4.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try using tail to copy the file continually:

```
tail -c +0 -f /proc/$pid/fd/$fd > filename
```

Of course, you will have to stop the tail process by hand (or some other external means) when the download has finished.

Comment: Works like a charm. I guess this was much easier than I thought, since all you need is really just another program that opens the same file to keep it around.

Answer (score 4):

The [fdlink](https://github.com/alhafoudh/fdlink) project, consisting of a Linux kernel module and simple application, purports to create a new link to an open file descriptor. I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 1):

This will get the job done, though not through by recovering the inode:

```
cp /proc/$PID/fd/$FD /tmp/blah
kill $PID
wget -c $URL -O /tmp/blah
```

Or just manually stop the download in Chrome if you don't want to kill the whole browser.

Comment: If only the problem were so simple that I could just resume-/re-download! I clarified the question to indicate that I can't assume I can re-download.

Comment: Sounds like trouble :-) It seems like any inode-based hacks are way too low-level and filesystem-specific.

Comment: Yeah, I just also added this to my question: if it makes any difference, I'm mainly concerned with ext4.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a hard link on this, you have to use the -s option (see `man ln`) so in the fd directory run `ls -f` and find out the filenumber (mostly two-digit numbers) and make a `ln NUMBER destination-file -s`